# Problem making system calls with PHP scripts

Tags: php

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php
  $fortune = `fortune`;
  echo $fortune;
?>
```

but the output is simply blank (no visible errors thrown).

However, if I run `php -a`, it works:

```
php > echo `fortune`;
Be careful of reading health books, you might die of a misprint.
        -- Mark Twain
php >
```

Am I missing a config directive or something that would cause this?

*Edit:* So, I tried running my script using `$ php-cgi fortunetest.php` and it worked as expected.  Maybe the issue is with Apache2?

Comment: This would probably get a better response on stackoverflow.com

Comment: What $PATH is Apache run with? Where does fortune live?

Comment: yeah, ask this question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, I found the solution:  `fortune` lived in `/usr/games`, so I thought it might be a `$PATH` issue, but when I did `su www-data` and ran `$ fortune` it worked as expected, and `/usr/games` was in `$PATH`.  Apparently, Apache was using a different `$PATH` variable even though it was running under user `www-data`, so I rewrote the script to use `/usr/games/fortune` instead of plain `fortune` and it worked.  Since `fortune` wasn't the point of the script, it was kind of a waste of time, but lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

the `fortune` command just outputs a quotation or famous quote for you. You can just simply store those [quotations](http://quotes.cat-v.org/) in a flat text file, or if you have a database, store them in a table. Then use the [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function or similar in PHP to generate a random number and use this number to get that row in the quotations file/table. This way, your PHP script is not dependent on whether the system has the `fortune` command installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use full paths like `/usr/games/fortune` instead of just `fortune`. Apache doesn't always expand paths automatically.

```
<?php passthru('/usr/games/fortune'); ?>
```

To find a full path do `which` in the shell e.g..

```
which fortune
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I don't know. However It might be you have to say echo `$fortune` instead.